# Codeigniter : redirect and Error 404

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, http-status-code-404

i'm trying to perform a redirection with Codeigniter using

```
// setting up flashdata
//...
// do a redirect
redirect('/', 'location', 404);
```

So the user will be redirected to the home page with a flashdata message.

But it doesn't work, and gives me a blank page

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter has to be a 301 or 302.

You would need to set a flashdata parameter to remember that the last page view was a 404.  Then in your index controller/action set the status code to 404:

```
$this->output->set_status_header(404, 'Not Found');
```

So, just use a normal homepage redirect:

```
redirect();
```